# Either a or b and either c or d is nonzero implies either ac+2bd or ad+bc is nonzero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: I'm trying to prove that a particular subset of $\Bbb R$ is a subgroup under multiplication, but I'm getting stuck on a little bit of the algebra.

If at least one of $a$ and $b$ and at least one of $c$ and $d$ are nonzero rational numbers, how can I show that at least one of $ac+2bd$ and $ad+bc$ is nonzero?  Do I have to break it into 4 cases?

Comment: If you want four cases, do this.

Case 1: $a \neq 0$, $c \neq 0$.
Case 2: $a \neq 0$, $d \neq 0$.
Case 3: $b \neq 0$, $c \neq 0$.
Case 4: $b \neq 0$, $d \neq 0$. 

Though it might take up less space if you do $a \neq 0$ first and then $b \neq 0$ second.

Comment: So I do have to do it in cases?  OK.  I can do that, I just thought there might be a faster way.  Thanks.

Comment: If $a=0\implies b\neq0\implies bd\neq0 \lor bc\neq0$

Comment: Just to be clear, the example $a=1=c$, $b=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}=-d$ shows that the "rational" bit is necessary.

Comment: Actually, isn't that a counterexample to your question?  I have $a,c$ are non-zero and rational so your condition is satisfied.

Comment: @lulu I maybe didn't specific well.  $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Q$ such that (either $a\ne 0$ or $b\ne 0$) and (either $c\ne 0$ or $d\ne 0$).

Comment: You should edit your question.  You specifically refer to a "subset of $\mathbb R$".

Comment: Is your set $\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q, a^2+b^2>0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cases might help.

Assume $ac+2bd=ad+bc=0$. If $a=0$, we conclude $bc=0$ and $2bd=0$; but as $a=0$ means $b\ne 0$, we get $c=0$ and $d=0$, contradiction.

Hence we may assume $a\ne 0$. 
Then $c=-\frac{2bd}{a}$ and $d=-\frac{bc}{a}$, so $c=\frac{2b^2c}{a^2}$. If $c\ne 0$, this tells us that $\sqrt{\frac 12}=\frac ba$, which is absurd with $a,b$ rational. We conclude $c=0$.
But then $2bd=0$ and $ad=0$; but as $c=0$ implies $d\ne 0$, we get $a=0$ and $b=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I think breaking into 4 cases (actually 6, because you need to check for $ad=-bc$ and $ac=-2bd$) should work, but you can also argue using only the latter expressions.

Take the first one and check under which conditions it's equal to zero; and then for each condition, show that the other can't be zero.